# when to call editor.apply?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

in my app I have up to 20 holidays that can be defined by the user, and when saving them to the shared preference editor I have it set up like this:

```
String checkhold = "0";
String holodate = g.getData82();// string is either "0" if no holidays entered, or, for example, "1,1,7,4,12,25, if January 1st, July 4th and December 25th is entered

if (!holodate.equals("0")) {

    checkhold = holodate;
    int value = 0;
    String splitHere = "[,]";
    String[] sToken = holodate.split(splitHere);
    int count = holodate.length() - checkhold.replace(",", "").length();
    g.setData92(emp, count);
    double holidayNumber = count * 0.5;
    passeditor.putDouble(holnums, holidayNumber);

if (count >= 0) {
    value = Integer.parseInt(sToken[0]);
    g.setData90(0, value);
    passeditor.putInt(holmonth1, value);passeditor.apply();
    value = Integer.parseInt(sToken[1]);
    g.setData91(0, value);
    passeditor.putInt(holday1, value);passeditor.apply();
    }

    if (count >= 2) {
    value = Integer.parseInt(sToken[2]);
    g.setData90(1, value);
    passeditor.putInt(holmonth2, value);passeditor.apply();
    value = Integer.parseInt(sToken[3]);
    passeditor.putInt(holday2, value);passeditor.apply();
    g.setData91(1, value);
    }
//....continue 18 more code blocks
}
```

As you can see I've called passeditor.apply 40 times,
But what I'm wondering is do I need to call passeditor.apply after every passeditor.put in the case of these 20 code blocks or can I call it once at the end of each code block, or can I just call it one time at the end of all 20 code blocks?
Just trying to eliminate unnecessary code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call it when you want save changes to `SharedPreferences` - you can call it once, on the end of editing.

Comment: Thanks that makes perfect sense

Answer (score 2):

You can do as follow

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("Name","name");
editor.putInt("integer",22);
.
.
.
editor.apply();//At the end save all by calling editor.apply()
```